# OAuth Authorization without login

Tags: oauth, authorize

I've been requested by a client to incorporate OAuth authentication within a REST service. The setup I am working with is client/user accessing a service directly. The service is not connecting to another service. I was asked to have OAuth implemented so that users/clients are authenticated by supplying the username and password in the authorization request and not have them log in via a web page. My client has read information from other sites like paypal (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/paypal-oauth2/) which lead him to believe this was possible. So my underlying question is how do I configure an Authoirzation Server to allow for authorization when supplied a password and username directly?

Peter

Answer (score 2):

The flow is called "**Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant**" and described in [4.3. Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) of RFC 6749 (OAuth 2.0).

In this flow, a client accesses the token endpoint without accessing the authorization endpoint. So, check the configuration of the token endpoint of your authorization server.